# How to create book app for android?

Tags: android

I want to build a simple book app for android that contains 100 pages of text-only content using android studio.
First activity to enter , 2 buttons for navigating to next and previous page and page number indicator. Also when page indicator clicked, a window pops up for entering specific page number.
Which way is better for this purpose ? Database or HTML method ?
Is there any source code or tutorial resources ?

Comment: Have you read http://developer.android.com/training/index.html ?

Comment: Google restricted that service for my country .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this using HTML method. What I did is I created HTML files for all the pages, then zipped all the pages.

After that unzipped it into android file system then using WebView I am able to view all the pages like a book app does.

I have added next page, previous page, and search button also.