# How to develop book application with chapter content that has text and images using database

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-sqlite

What would be the best way to implement a book application which has text and images in a chapter as shown in the following examples of another application's screenshots.

[image]

I would like to be able to produce the following for my application without hard coding the strings into the textviews, I would like to be able to retrieve the data from the database.

Comment: In which format you are saving chapter data into your database?
Add your table structure here.

Comment: My initial thought was to use a table with the following fields: id, chapter and text but I then I realised I will incur problems on the placement of images that are in between text.

Comment: I am sharing my point of view below in answer. Let me know if you have any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [create-book-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160461/how-to-create-book-app-for-android)

> I have done this using HTML method. What I did is I created HTML files
>   for all the pages, then zipped all the pages. After that unzipped it
>   into android file system then using WebView I am able to view all the
>   pages like a book app does. I have added next page, previous page, and
>   search button also.

My best recommendation is to store those chapters as HTML files and display them using one of those 2 librarys [noties](https://github.com/noties/Markwon) + [MarkdownView](https://github.com/mukeshsolanki/MarkdownView-Android)

I have used this strategy myself before to display long content with HTML response that included tables-images and style inside the HTML.

Comment: Thank you I have looked at the libraries I think this one is ideal, thank you, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, I am sharing my point of view:- ***(If you have to implement using database and native way)***

Table structure would be :-

1. id => Integer
2. chapter_id => Integer
3. data => Text (It contains image path and formatted text String.)
4. type => enum('text','image')

And you can add more columns according to your need.

So, you need to fire query like:-

```
SELECT * From table_name WHERE chapter_id=9 order by id ASC.
```

> Note:- You need to take care of inserting data, that you have to add
>   chapter data sequentially.

So using query you can **get all the data in model array** (Model is same like your table structure.)

Then using **Recycler view** you can display **multiple views** using your type (image / text).